I've set a hotkey in Python and it doesn't work, how do I set up a working hotkey?
I am trying to make a program that will click a button really quickly for personal needs, but right now I've only come so far as to click the left button. I am trying to make a hotkey to turn it off, but it doesn't work. I CANT USE THREADING, that's why its all in the same loop.
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
#3 We define the spam command
spamming=False
def off():
      global spamming
      spamming=False
def spam():
    global clickidy
    clickidy=tipidytype.get()
    global spamming
    spamming= True
    while spamming==True:
      pyautogui.click(clicks=1)
      root.update()
      try:
           if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
                off()
      except:
           nothing=0
#1 Lets set up our window
root=Tk()
root["bg"]="#fafafa"
root.title("Sigma clicker")
root.geometry("400x110")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
frame=Frame()
frame.place(relx=0,rely=0,relheight=1,relwidth=1)
#2 Now we can add interface
title = Label(frame, text="Enter the button for spamming here")
title.place(x=15, y=15)
tipidytype=Entry(frame,bg="white")
tipidytype.place(x=15, y=45)
tester = Entry(frame, bg="white")
tester.place(x=250,y=45)
testtext=Label(frame, text="Focus here before starting")
testtext.place(x=250,y=15)
button = Button(frame,text="      On     ", bg="gray", command=spam)
button.place(x=15,y=75)
off=Button(frame,text="Off", bg="gray", command=off)
off.place(x=250,y=75)
def window_exit():
      global spamming
      spamming=False
      root.destroy()
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", window_exit)
root.mainloop()

I've tried making delays and two (2) different kinds of keyboard input(the listener didn't work' because it requires a loop).


when you say "It doesn't work", what do you mean specifically? 2) out of curiosity, why can't you use threading?


1)It doesn't stop the clicker. 2)It just doesn't work for me.

Rename the off button to other name as it overrides the off() function.

You could use a .after() loop for the clicking. Regarding the hotkey a solution could be binding <Key> on root and cheking if event.keysym == 'q', but this will only work if the GUI is active. If the spammed button is not within your Tk app then this answer shows how to set up a system hotkey.
Here is a sample with the binding method refactored into an OOP approach:
from tkinter import *


class Spammer(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # replaces root=Tk() as self of class
        self.spamming = False  # use instance variable instead of global variable
        self.clickidy = None
        # build GUI
        self["bg"] = "#fafafa"
        self.title("Sigma clicker")
        self.geometry("400x110")
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        frame = Frame()
        frame.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=1, relwidth=1)
        title = Label(frame, text="Enter the button for spamming here")
        title.place(x=15, y=15)
        self.tipidytype = Entry(frame, bg="white")  # make this an instance variable to access from other function
        self.tipidytype.place(x=15, y=45)
        tester = Entry(frame, bg="white")
        tester.place(x=250, y=45)
        testtext = Label(frame, text="Focus here before starting")
        testtext.place(x=250, y=15)
        button = Button(frame, text="      On     ", bg="gray", command=self.start)
        button.place(x=15, y=75)
        off = Button(frame, text="Off", bg="gray", command=self.off)
        off.place(x=250, y=75)
        # bindings
        self.bind('<Key>', self.on_key)  # bind keypress on root → only working while Tk window is in focus
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.window_exit)

    def on_key(self, event):
        ''' check if q button is pressed while window is active '''
        if event.keysym == 'q':
            self.off()

    def off(self):
        ''' toggle spamming off '''
        self.spamming = False

    def start(self):
        ''' initiate spamming '''
        self.clickidy = self.tipidytype.get()
        self.spamming = True
        self.spam()

    def spam(self):
        ''' actual spamming with .after "loop" '''
        if self.spamming:
            print('click')  # print debugging for testing the click loop
            # pyautogui.click(clicks=1)  # maby leave this commented for testing ;)
            # spamming to fast will block the main thread and make the GUI and callbacks unresponsive!
            self.after(1000, self.spam)  # click again after 1000 ms if spamming remains True

    def window_exit(self):
        ''' this is unneccesary cleanup '''
        self.spamming = False
        self.destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Spammer()
    app.mainloop()



EDIT

It does work if you don't start the actual clicking, it start clicking as usual but then it crashes after a while(10-20sec). –
Carny pex


If you set the clicking to be very fast (by reducing the miliseconds in the .after() method) this will block the main thread so the binding of "q" will not work... in this case your only option is to use threading which you don't want to –
Jan_B

Here is solution 2 using a seperate thread for the clicking and a hotkey ALT+Q for stopping instead of .after() and tk bindings:
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
from system_hotkey import SystemHotkey  # pip install pywin32 and system_hotkey


class Spammer(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        [...]
        # create a Hotkey for turing the clicking off
        hk = SystemHotkey()
        hk.register(['alt', 'q'], callback=self.off)
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.window_exit)
        # set up thread variable
        self.thr = None

    def off(self, event=None):
        ''' toggle spamming off '''
        self.spamming = False
        self.thr.join()
        self.thr = None

    def start(self):
        ''' initiate spamming by creating a new thread'''
        self.clickidy = self.tipidytype.get()
        self.thr = Thread(target=self.spam)  # create a Thread object
        self.spamming = True
        self.thr.start()  # instead of calling spam() start spam() in a separate thread

    def spam(self):
        ''' actual spamming outside main thread using sleep '''
        if self.spamming:
            print('click')
            # since this is run in a seperate thread sleep will not block mainloop
            sleep(0.1)
            self.spam()

    def window_exit(self):
        ''' this is unneccesary cleanup '''
        if self.spamming:
            self.spamming = False
            self.thr.join()
        self.destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Spammer()
    app.mainloop()



It does work if you don't start the actual clicking, it start clicking as usual but then it crashes after a while(10-20sec).

@Carnypex what do you mean by crashing? Is there an traceback for an error or does your computer freeze? If you set the clicking to be very fast (by reducing the miliseconds in the .after() method) this will block the main thread so the binding of "q" will not work... in this case your only option is to use threading which you don't want to

@Carnypex I added another solution using a "real" hotkey and threading. Please check if this solves the issue for you. If not please specify the crashing of yours

I mean that it closes the program with an error

@Jan_B I am guessing RecursionError because of the self.spam()

The hotkey (q for your case) is working, but calling off() inside spam() raises exception because off is a reference to Button widget.
# command assigned correct refernece to off()
off=Button(frame,text="Off", bg="gray", command=off)  
# but now off is a reference to a button widget, not the off()

Using other name for the button can fix the issue:
off_btn = Button(frame,text="Off", bg="gray", command=off)
off_btn.place(x=250, y=75)

Note that you don't need to call off() inside spam().  Just break out the while loop when key q is pressed:
def spam():
    ...
    while spamming==True:
        ...
        try:
            if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
                break  # break out the while loop
        ...

